# Excel VBA select new usedrange portion of a column

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Data Sample]

Hi All.

I need your help please.

I want to apply a formula to the new rows that I've just added.  I have a line of code I use for a full set of data, but I'm not sure how to modify it, or if there is a better way to do it.

I'm a bit out of my league with this line of code, I understand what it's doing but I didn't write it.

```
Sheets("Closed Loop").Range(varPastePos).Offset(0, 2).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, columnsize:=1).FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"
```

`varPastePos` is the position the new data was pasted, in this case `$F$28`

Any ideas?

Comment: an easier alternative is to format the range as Table (Home tab > Format as Table) so that formulas are auto populated when you add a new row to the table

Comment: Learning to format your code in a readable fashion will do wonders for your ability to actually read the code.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens that would not be valid code in VBA so it will be harder for people to copy it

Comment: @Slai Thanks for responding. That would be a possible solution if I didn't need to put the date of the Sunday of the current week (21/08/2016) against the new records.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'm afraid your response doesn't make a lot of sense to me, can you provide an example? For it's correct purpose, I think this line of code is quite elegant

Comment: @ThomasInzina I think I stole this line of code from something you shared with me initially.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Range().FillDown` to extend a pre-existing formula.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2", "A" & lastRow).FillDown
```

You can `FillDown` multiple columns at once like this:

```
 Range("A2", "D" & lastRow).FillDown
```

You can do it all in one line like this:

`Range("A2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).FillDown`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get it all in one line of code, but between you and Slai, it seems that isn't achievable.  I won't have time to work on this again until next week but I will try out both options.

Comment: Thanks for that.  FillDown is reliant on content in the adjacent column isn't it?

Comment: FillDown works just like dragging the fill handle on a worksheet.  Then formula will change based on the relative reference `=$A1` will not change  `A1` will increment `=A2`,`=A3`,`=A4`...etc.

Comment: Thanks, I used Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).FillDown to copy down the formulas.  I don't like to specifying the formula but it's unlikely anyone will break it.

Comment: For entering the date I ended up going with:

    varPastePos = Range(varPastePos).Offset(0, -4).Address
    Sheets("Closed Loop").Range("F1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -5).Select
    Range(Selection, varPastePos).Formula = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Are both ranges on Sheets("Closed Loop")?

Comment: Yes. My grammar two up is terrible. What I was trying to say is I like to always specify the exact formula as all my reports are saved on SharePoint for the team to view and there is always a possibility that someone comes through and does something without meaning to.

Comment: The main thing is that it works.  But I would not select the range.

Comment: How would you get around using select? The only way I can see is with a variable which seems a lot of effort for one use. I have been eliminating select as much as possible, on your advice, but in some instances like this, I don't know how to avoid it.

Comment: I would use the extra variable but this will also  work: `With Sheets("Closed Loop") .Range(.Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -5), Range(varPastePos).Offset(0, -4)).Formula = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")  End With
`

Answer (score 0):

`.UsedRange` would also include formatted blank cells so it is not reliable for finding the last used row.

```
Set ws = Sheets("Closed Loop")
Set cell1 = ws.Range(varPastePos) ' F28
Set cell2 = cell1.End(xlDown)     ' F32 ? the last cell with data below F28. Similar to clicking on F28 and pressing Ctrl + down
Set rngF = ws.Range(cell1, cell2) ' F28:F32
Set rngH = rngF.Offset(, 2)        ' H28:H32
rngH.FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get it all in one line of code, but between you and Slai, it seems that isn't achievable.  I won't have time to work on this again until next week but I will try out both options.

Comment: @HelenRolls maybe something like `Range(['Closed Loop'!F28], ['Closed Loop'!F28].End(xlDown)).Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "My Formula"`

Comment: Thanks for your input.